# Execute code when animation finished jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$(this).animate({"left": left+"px"}, { queue: false, duration: 500 })
.animate({"top": top+"px"}, { queue: false, duration: 500 })
.animate({"height": size+"px"}, { queue: false, duration: 500 })
.animate({"width": size+"px"}, { queue: false, duration: 500 });
```

I´m a beginner at jQuery. I want the following code to run when the animation has finished:

```
$('#map').css('cursor','pointer');
```

How can I do that? And also, if my code is bad, I would be very thankful if you improved it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could animate them all at once and use the ["complete" callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate):

```
$(this).animate({
    left:   left + 'px',
    top:    top  + 'px',
    height: size + 'px',
    width:  size + 'px'
}, {
    queue:    false,
    duration: 500,
    complete: function() {
        $('#map').css('cursor','pointer');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(this).animate(
    { // map of the properties to animate
        'left': left + 'px',
        'top': top + 'px',
        'height': size + 'px',
        'width': size + 'px'
    },
    500, // animation duration
    function() { // function to execute when animation is completed
        $('#map').css('cursor','pointer');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(this).animate({"left": left+"px"}, { queue: false, duration: 500 })
    .animate({"top": top+"px"}, { queue: false, duration: 500 })
    .animate({"height": size+"px"}, { queue: false, duration: 500 })
    .animate({"width": size+"px"}, { queue: false, duration: 500,
      complete : function() {
         $('#map').css('cursor','pointer');
          }
    });
```

It should be that way if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).animate({
  "left": left+"px",
  "top": top+"px",
  "height": size+"px",
  "width": size+"px"
},{
  queue: false, 
  duration: 500,
  complete: function(){
    $('#map').css('cursor','pointer');
  }
});
```